# Как сделать что бы при отправке формы в PHP попадали данные не из input?

Tags: javascript, html

При отправке контактной формы отправляются заполняемы поля (Имя, телефон, Email). Они приходят в норме. Имеются еще данные, которые пользователь выбирает, а не заполняет[image], в конце происходит подсчет результатов и все данные должны отправится, но они либо отправляются частично, либо не отправляются вообще.
`введите сюда код`https://jsfiddle.net/b0m74wf3/`введите сюда код` ВОТ САМИ КОДЫ
В CSS php файл отправки формы.
Приходит вот такое сообщение[image]
Сделать вместо этого input radio не вариант, код большой, все слетает. Помогите разобраться со скриптом, я в js новичок.

Comment: `<input type=hidden .../>` а значение выставляй обработчиком клика по ссылке

Comment: как обработчиком клика? приведите пример пожалуйста

Comment: <a onclick= которы

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам идея для размышление
Тут можно всё сократить, но я сделал на быструю руку, удачи вам ^-^

```js
const sel1 = document.querySelectorAll(".select-1");
const res_sel1 = document.querySelector("#result-select-1");
const sel2 = document.querySelectorAll(".select-2");
const res_sel2 = document.querySelector("#result-select-2");

for(let i = 0; i < sel1.length; i++){
  sel1[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    res_sel1.value = this.innerHTML;
  })
}

for(let i = 0; i < sel2.length; i++){
  sel2[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    res_sel2.value = this.innerHTML;
  })
}

function send(){
  console.log(res_sel1.value, res_sel2.value);
}
```

```css
.block{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.select-1,
.select-2{
  padding: 12px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="select-1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="select-1">Text 2</div>
  <div class="select-1">Text 3</div>
  <div class="select-1">Text 4</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="result-select-1">
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="select-2">Text 5</div>
  <div class="select-2">Text 6</div>
  <div class="select-2">Text 7</div>
  <div class="select-2">Text 8</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="result-select-2">
</div>

<button onclick="send()">Отправить</button>
```